# Guardar un JSON en postgres desde php

Tags: php, json, postgresql

Como guardaría desde php un json en un campo json de postgres . este es la tabla en postgres

```
CREATE TABLE graficas.PREDIO_POLIGONO(
  id_predio INT NOT NULL,
  poligono JSON
);
```

Comment: lo haces como insertar cualquier dato pero antes de insertar el json podrias cambiarlo a un array asociativo: $data = json_decode($json, true); y esa $data es la que insertas en tu DB

Comment: Gracias a Diego Avila por su respuesta pude ver gracias a esto que tenia un error en sintaxis la cual corregí voy a publicar el código para cualquier otra persona que tenga duda.

Answer (score 1):

//creo una función
function getInsert(){
//creo manualmente un json para probar y lo coloco en una variable llamada $hola
$hola = '{"marcadores": [{"lat": 10.058490,"lng": -69.372416,"color": "blue","etiqueta":"2","titulo": "Izquierda"   },{"lat": 10.059353,"lng": -69.372522,"color": "gold","etiqueta": "1","titulo": "Centro Dos"}]}';

```
//se hable la conexión a la base de datos
$dbconn = obtenerConexion();

//creo la variable $query donde pongo la cadena SQL e inserto en este caso el id y el JSON que esta almacenado en la varible $hola
$query = "INSERT INTO graficas.predio_poligono VALUES(1,'$hola')";

//Ejecuto el query y agarro el resultado en la variable $result
$result = pg_query($dbconn, $query); 

//pregunto si el $result se inserto y mando el comentario pertinente  
if($result){
    echo "inserto";
} else{
    echo "no inserto";
}
```

//cierro la conexión de la base de datos postgres
    pg_close($dbconn);
}

//imprimo por consola el resultado de la función
echo getInsert();

Comment: A quien pueda interesar este es el código completo ya inserta  gracias a Diego Avila por su respuesta.

Comment: deberás explicarlo, dando clic en editar pues solo poner código se considera de baja calidad

Comment: listo puse unos comentarios al código disculpen aun no se bien como poner todo en orden espero entiendan el código.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

Primero debes decodificar el Json algo asi:

```
$mi_json_var = json_decode($mi_json)
```

para mayor detalle te sugiero leer esto: [Json decode php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)

Ahora debes insertar esta variable en tu BD algo asi:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (campo1, json) VALUES (1, '$mi_json_var')";
```

Bueno espero te ayude y suerte..!!